# syntax error loop (TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable)

Tags: python, pandas

how to solve the problem?
i have a something homework with python, i want to loop a data in csv, this my code

```
import pandas as p
import numpy as np

df = p.read_csv("mlp.csv")
dataInp = df.drop(["output"],axis=1)
dataOup = df["output"]

v1 = 1.718946
v2 = -1.263178
v3 = -1.083092
w1 = -0.541180 
w2 = 0.54360

i=0
j=0
for i in dataInp:
    for j in dataInp:
        z_in = (dataInp(i,j)*v1)
print(z_in)
```

and error output :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "user\a.py", line 22, in <module>
    z_in = (dataInp(i,j)*v1)
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using parentheses when you should be using square brackets on the line `z_in = (dataInp(i,j)*v1)`

The corrected code is `z_in = (dataInp[i,j]*v1)`

Because you are using parentheses, python interprets it as if you are trying to call `dataInp` as a function.